# Pyspark / Dataframe: Add new column that keeps nested list as nested list

Tags: python, dataframe, format, pyspark

I have a basic question about dataframes and adding a column that should contain a nested list. This is basically the problem:

```
b = [[['url.de'],['name']],[['url2.de'],['name2']]]

a = sc.parallelize(b)
a = a.map(lambda p: Row(URL=p[0],name=p[1]))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(a)

list1 = [[['a','s', 'o'],['hallo','ti']],[['a','s', 'o'],['hallo','ti']]]
c = [b[0] + [list1[0]],b[1] + [list1[1]]]

#Output looks like this:
[[['url.de'], ['name'], [['a', 's', 'o'], ['hallo', 'ti']]], 
 [['url2.de'], ['name2'], [['a', 's', 'o'], ['hallo', 'ti']]]]
```

To Create a new Dataframe from this output, I´m trying to create a new schema:

```
schema = df.withColumn('NewColumn',array(lit("10"))).schema
```

I then use it to create the new DataFrame:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(c,schema)
df.map(lambda x: x).collect()

#Output
[Row(URL=[u'url.de'], name=[u'name'], NewColumn=[u'[a, s, o]', u'[hallo, ti]']),
 Row(URL=[u'url2.de'], name=[u'name2'], NewColumn=[u'[a, s, o]', u'[hallo, ti]'])]
```

The Problem now is that, the nested list was transformed into a list with two unicode entries instead of keeping the original format.

I think this is due to my definition of the new Column "... array(lit("10"))".

What do I have to use in order to keep the original format?

Comment: df['NewColumn'].astype(str).values for remove unicode from columns values.

Comment: doesn´t work: "TypeError: unexpected type: <type 'type'>". And I dont want a string as result I want the nested list as result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly inspect the schema of the dataframe by calling `df.schema`. You can see that in the given scenario we have the following:

```
StructType(
  List(
    StructField(URL,ArrayType(StringType,true),true),
    StructField(name,ArrayType(StringType,true),true),
    StructField(NewColumn,ArrayType(StringType,false),false)
  )
)
```

The `NewColumn` that you added is an `ArrayType` column whose entries are all `StringType`. So anything that is contained in the array will be converted to a string, even if it is itself an array. If you want to have nested arrays (2 layers), then you need to change your schema so that the the `NewColumn` field has an `ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType,False),False)` type. You can do this by explicitly defining the schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType, StringType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("URL", ArrayType(StringType(),True), True),
    StructField("name", ArrayType(StringType(),True), True),
    StructField("NewColumn", ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType(),False),False), False)])
```

Or by changing your code by having the `NewColumn` be defined by nesting the `array` function, `array(array())`:

```
df.withColumn('NewColumn',array(array(lit("10")))).schema
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thumbs up! Didn´t think of this easy way of doing it.